# Push and update plugin

Tags: bazaar, bazaar-plugins

1.I was trying to use the push-and-update plugin and failed. after solving the reported error (i change the plugin folder name to push_and_update) all errors disappeared , but its seems that nothing happened --> the "remote" branch still needs to be updated manually.
Please help.

1. I tried to attach an detailed description of an workflow i prepared , in order to get your comments. the upload was failed due to the fact that i'm new user in this forum. do i have another way to attach image?

thanks
Gil Idelson

Answer (score 1):

I think there must already exist a workingtree on the server.
You can use `bzr checkout` to create one.